# How make scheduler with a counter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my **MySQL** database I have a table called `TABLE_MAIN`. I need to add new data to this table from other tables every hour. In my case they are `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`. I need to run SQL statement below every hour. In the same time I need to set new values for `A.TIME_KEY` and `B.MONTH_KEY` every hour.

For example an hour later the value for `A.TIME_KEY` must be `2018-01-05 01:00:00`. In the same time `B.MONTH_KEY` has the same value `2018-01-01`. The value for `B.MONTH_KEY` changed only when will be next month. For example `2018-02-01`.

How can do I such scheduler with a counter in MySQL?

**SQL**:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_MAIN (
  ID,
  TIME_KEY,
  STATUS,
  OBJECT_NAME,
  OBJECT_DESCRIPTION
) VALUES (
  SELECT
    A.ID
    A.TIME_KEY
    A.STATUS
    B.OBJECT_NAME
    B.OBJECT_DESCRIPTION
  FROM 
    TABLE_A AS A
  INNER JOIN 
    TABLE_B AS B
  ON 
    A.ID = B.ID_OBJECT
  WHERE 
    A.TIME_KEY="2018-01-05 00:00:00"
  AND
    B.MONTH_KEY="2018-01-01"
);
```

Comment: I don't get it? Do you always want `TIME_KEY` to be the current hour and `MONTH_KEY` the first day of current month?

Comment: Hello! `MONTH_KEY` always has first day of the month. For example: `2018-01-01`, `2018-02-01`, `2018-03-01` e.t.c. It just show what month it is. I noticed that the data in the `TABLE_A` is two hours behind. So if I use `HOUR(A.TIME_KEY) = HOUR(NOW()) - 2` it does not take into account the data between 22:00 - 24:00. Do you understand me? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Lets say if current time is `2018-06-01 00:00:00` I need to send `2012-05-30 22:00:00` value to `A.TIME_KEY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and set the last parts of DATE or DATETIME to constant values:

```
WHERE 
    A.TIME_KEY  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H-00-00')
  AND
    B.MONTH_KEY = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

If the data is "two hours behind", just replace `NOW()` with `NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR`

```
WHERE 
    A.TIME_KEY  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H-00-00')
  AND
    B.MONTH_KEY = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about using [date_add()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) function for this task?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek `NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` is equivalent to `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR)` or `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)`. So you can use what ever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it following way:

First, you need to build a proper Insert query and then put it in to a Event Scheduler.

Turn on your scheduler:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;


CREATE 
    EVENT `Event_Name` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2019-02-10 00:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TABLE_MAIN (
  ID,
  TIME_KEY,
  STATUS,
  OBJECT_NAME,
  OBJECT_DESCRIPTION
) 
      SELECT
    A.ID
    A.TIME_KEY
    A.STATUS
    B.OBJECT_NAME
    B.OBJECT_DESCRIPTION
  FROM 
    TABLE_A AS A
  INNER JOIN 
    TABLE_B AS B
  ON 
    A.ID = B.ID_OBJECT
  WHERE
      CASE WHEN DAY(B.MONTH_KEY) = 1
           THEN  month(B.MONTH_KEY) = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
           ELSE   month(B.MONTH_KEY) = month(NOW())
      END
     AND
     CASE WHEN HOUR(A.TIME_KEY) < 2
          THEN Date(A.TIME_KEY) = Date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND hour(A.TIME_KEY) = hour(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
          ELSE Date(A.TIME_KEY) = Date(NOW()) and hour(A.TIME_KEY) = hour(NOW()- INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
     END
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your example. I noticed that the data in the `TABLE_A` is two hours behind. So if I use `HOUR(A.TIME_KEY) = HOUR(NOW()) - 2` in your code it does not take into account the data between 22:00 - 24:00. Do you understand me? How I need update the code in that case?

Comment: Lets say if current time is `2018-06-01 00:00:00`  I need to send  `2012-06-30 22:00:00` value to `A.TIME_KEY`.

Comment: I think u need to send `2018-5-30 22:00:00` in above example. I understood. Will update query

Comment: Can you provide a SQLFiddle or Create & Insert queries for all involved tables in order to validate the result of what I'm trying in query here?

Comment: is it possible for you to provide that?

Comment: Hello! `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` has pretty simple structure. `TABLE_A` has 3 colomn: `ID`, `TIME_KEY` and `STATUS`. `TABLE_B` has also 3 colomn: `ID_OBJECT`, `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_DESCRIPTION`. This tables has too much data and I don't know how I can send it to you. I think you can fill them with fake data just for test.

Comment: What do you think about using [date_add()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) function for this task?